# raphael js .serialize() i get empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

i try to serialize raphael's canvas to send it via form and get a png file.
in my  section i have:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/raphael.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/raphael.serialize.js"></script>
```

and in  window.onload = function () { ... i do some drawings, then i have some  that i use as a buttons, but when i try to get a serialized value of raphael's canvas i get empty array.

```
$('#btnEmail').click(function() {
    $("input#jsonsvg").val(paper.serialize.json());
     });
```

what's wrong with this code?
try to go to http://alfen.linuxpl.info/konf/foundation/index_2.html and click on a 'Wyslij email'3rd blue button from the left that shoud fire up an event to paper.serialize()

i appreaciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely to be a problem with Raphael V2.0. The author has removed namespace functionality and it's caused a lot of plugins that worked with the previous version to now break. Do you get any JS errors?

My advice is to create your own serialize function.

Comment: thanks. i have switched to older version of Raphael and it is working now. i have no experience about creating my own serialize function, so i had to downgrade it. big thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a refactored version, it works with Raphael 2.0 and handles all elements and transformations:

https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.JSON